# Good tool hand box

Tags: hand-tools

I have a great old Rubbermaid Roughneck hand box that has broken a latch after 20 or so years.  I am appalled at the quality and selection of boxes at the major stores today. Mostly flimsy and have thin sheet metal latches with sharp edges.

The good brands are oversized wheeled sets or such a "heavy duty" design that there is a great deal of wasted space. Home depot seems to sell mostly house branded tool bags, but I need something for garage storage that will close for dust protection and stack with my other boxes that hold occasionally used tools and related supplies. It doesn't have to be extra heavy duty, just not flimsy.

Any suggestions on a good brand that offers a selection of sizes and is available in the USA?

Comment: Can you **repair** your "great old Rubbermaid Roughneck hand box that has broken a latch ?  I try not to participate in the current - everything is disposable - sickness that is pervasive in the *endless conspicuous consumption  ideology that is American capitalism*. It is difficult when manufactures subscribe to this ideology but i try.    I.E.  try to fix or re-purpose something instead of sending it to the landfill.

Comment: Product requests are specifically off-topic.

Comment: You could make one just the way you want it to be, and then pass it on to your heirs and their heirs and --. On a side note: i find it humorous that Rubbermaid is the Quality in this situation.

Comment: @Alaska Man Rubbermaid did at one time make some excellent middle priced tool boxes out of very durable plastics.  Like so many things today, retail purchasers have migrated toward the rock bottom price while trades seem to have moved into high end brands. That has left the middle market, homeowner consumers adrift.

Comment: Sorry for the off topic.  I'll remember next time.

Comment: @Pooneil  see my first comment !

Answer (score 1):

My grandfather had an ancient toolbox with a broken hasp. He attached the ends of an old belt to it with grommets (iirc). The buckle connected to the box, the holed end to the lid. I bet you can figure out how it closed...

Answer (score 0):

Go check out sears craftsmen they never let me down.  You can by craftsmen brand tools at some big box stores. I know Ace hardware has craftsmen tools.

Comment: To future visitors of this site, Sears was a brick and mortar store that specialized in home goods and sold the popular Craftsman line of tools. It barely survived bankruptcy in early 2019. In 2023, it went bankrupt for the final time after selling off Kenmore and Craftsman.

Comment: You may  want to look at  what year we are and not the future.

Comment: I'll stick with my prediction :)

Comment: Sear is gone, Craftsman is still manufactured as of 2019. Lowes home improvement centers ( in Alaska ) carries their line of tools.

Comment: @AlaskaMan: so is craftsman, except in name only. you used to be able to take a broken craftsman tool to any sears at any time, and they would replace it for free, no receipt, no questions. now it's all over-seas junk trading on the good will of the name...

Comment: We all did thats why they are gone. Buy at a yard sale ,bring it back was great.

Comment: @dandavis  , I took in more than one ratchet that failed and was given a shiny new one.   Overseas junk, it’s the,  profit   For the  sake of greed  American way.   Hey  gubment you can’t tell me I have to  Pay a livable wage.